# ManyToMany Test Fixtures (Yaml) in Play Framework 1.2.x

Tags: java, playframework, yaml, fixtures

I'm using Play! 1.2.4 + Morhpia / MongoDB.

My models are Salons and Stylists which share a many to many relationship. I am however unable to define the test data correctly to represent this relationship.

Here's what I have done

```
Salon(salon1):
  name: salon1
  city: singapore
  country: singapore

Stylist(stylist1):
  firstName: stylist1
  lastName: stylist1
  title: Stylist 1
  price: $100
  salons: [salon1]
```

With this data, the stylist contains the reference to the salon but not vice-versa.

How to achieve two way referencing?

Thanks,
Sri

---

Here are the model classes ..

```
@Entity("salons")
public class Salon extends Model {
  // ...
  @Reference
  @ManyToMany
  public List<Stylist> stylists;
  // ...
}

@Entity("stylists")
public class Stylist extends Model {
  // ..
  @Reference
  @ManyToMany
  public List<Salon> salons;
  // ..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by two way referencing?

If you mean you want to be able to access Stylists from your Salon entity in code, then you will need to have something like this:

```
public class Salon extends Model {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "salon_stylist", ...)
    public List<Stylist> stylists;

    ...
}
```

And your Stylist entity can look like this:

```
public class Stylist extends Model {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "salon_stylist", ...)
    public List<Salon> salons;

    ...
}
```

Then your yml can look like this:

```
Salon(salon1):
  name: salon1
  city: singapore
  country: singapore

Salon(salon2):
  name: salon2
  city: tokyo
  country: japan

Stylist(stylist1):
  firstName: stylist1
  lastName: stylist1
  title: Stylist 1
  price: $100
  salons: 
    - salon1
    - salon2
```

Just saying that stylist1 belongs to salon1 and salon2 should be enough in the yml (i.e. you shouldn't have to declare the same in the two salon yml entries).

Comment: I want to access stylists from a salon, for example salon1.stylists.get(0). I can already so stylist1.salons.get(0)

Comment: In the above code that should be possible.  So if you do: Salon salon1 = Salon.find("name = ?", "salon1"); and then you should have access to the stylists like you want.  Using the example above, salon1.stylists.get(0) should return the object representing stylist1.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I use Morphia and a MongoDB data store. Included my model classes in the question. Thanks.

Comment: is stylist1.salons null or an empty list? also, if you query stylist1 directly, does it know that it belongs to salon1?

Comment: stylist1.salons is valid with the correct Salon reference. salon1.stylists is an empty list.

Comment: just out of curiosity, if you switch your yml the other way around so that the stylist is declared first and then remove the [salon1] thing and declare stylist1 in salon1, does that mean the problem is reversed? (i.e. stylist1.salons returns an empty list and salons1.stylists returns the correct salon?)