# How to make one-to-one mapping playframework

Tags: java, database, jpa, playframework, one-to-one

I'm trying to set a one-to-one mapping between two tables by using playframework.I would like to create rating list for each user after this mapping. However, I couldn't. Could you help me?
My two seperate classes are like that:

`User.java`

```java
package models;

import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User extends Model {
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public String password;
    public String username;
    public Date lastlogin;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
}
```

`UserRating.java`

```java
package models;

import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "`userrating`")
public class UserRating extends Model {
    public double rating;    


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @MapsId


    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    public User user;
}
```

My yaml file is that:

```
User(19):
    name: freud
    surname: lily
    password: x56
    username: freud
    lastlogin: 2010-05-02
User(20):
    name: osman
    surname: özsu
    password: 798
    username: osman
    lastlogin: 2004-12-11


UserRating(1):
    rating: 1.2
    user: User(2)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a copy of your source code, but annotation are not in a correct place. They must stand before the attribute they are related to, not after. So the \@Id and \@GeneratedValue in the User class are not correct. I am quite sure this code isn't even compiling.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to use \@Id and \@GeneratedValue annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample of my user class :

```
@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class User extends Model implements BasicModel<Long>
{
    @Id
    public Long         idUser;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(unique=true)
    public String       mail;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Module.class)
    public List<Module> contributors;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String      password;
    @Constraints.Required
    public String       firstName;
    @Constraints.Required
    public String       lastName;

    public static Model.Finder<String, User> find = new Finder<String,User>(
            String.class, User.class);
}
```

The field idUser is my id, so the @Id annotation is one line BEFORE the daclaration of that attribute.

Your solution won't work because :

- There is no field named id_user in the user table. You should add this lines :

  @Id
  public Long idUser;

In your user table so that there will be a id_user field in your table.

- Remove all the annotations that, I am quite sure, you don't even know what is their usefullness.

So, try something like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User extends Model {

    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public String password;
    public String username;
    public Date lastlogin;
}
```

And :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`userrating`")
public class UserRating extends Model {
    public double rating;    

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
    public User user;
}
```

The user is the id only if you want to have only one rating per user. Anyway, there should be one id in your class.

Comment: I applied your suggestions. However, I encountered a different error:                                                            JPA error A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): A Foreign key refering models.User from models.UserRating has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Comment: I made a type in the JoinColumn of UserRating. It is id_user instead of user_id. You should check the name of the generated field in your data base. I edited the code.

Comment: I changed the type. However, new error is like that: 
Execution exception

RuntimeException occured : Cannot load fixture initial-data.yml: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.User
                                                                    I think it is about assigning value to 'user' object in yaml file. Is it correct?

Comment: I forgot to say that there is no need to use \@Id annotation because it creates id automatically. I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your yaml should look like :

```
users:
    - &user1 !!models.User
       name: freud
       surname: lily
       [...]

UserRating:
    rating: 1.2
    user: *user1
```

The & char is to make a reference to an object and the * char is for linking to a reference.
I posted an answer about which may be more usefull :
[How to populate a ManyToMany relationship using YAML on Play Framework 2.1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298173/how-to-populate-a-manytomany-relationship-using-yaml-on-play-framework-2-1-x/25291733#25291733)
Note that the ids are genrated automatically, no need to specify them.

Comment: I wrote these lines in yaml file. It gives an error like that:        
Execution exception

RuntimeException occured : Cannot load fixture initial-data.yml: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:models.User; exception=Class not found: models.User                                                          I think it is about version of playframework. I use 1.2.5. Your suggestion is not valid for my version. Is it right?

Comment: If you are working on 1.2.5, than maybe all of my answer may not apply to you since I am using 2.3. You should edit to state this at the beginning of your post.

Comment: Sorry for not stating the version at the beginning. Could you suggest anything about how to assign value to 'user' object for play 1.2.5 version? @Moebius

Comment: @michaelscolfield I am sorry but I don't know anything about play 1.

Comment: OK.There is no problem. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial worked for me:
https://biese.wordpress.com/2008/10/02/howto-entity-bean-one-to-one-relationship/

It cover two different cases of OneToOne relations:

- Unidirectional One-To-One relationship
- Bidirectional One-To-One relationship